# Is there any reason to use final specifier with unions?

Tags: c++, c++11

The *final specifier* can be used with classes or structs to forbid inheriting from them. In such case we only need to mark our class/struct as `final`:

```
class Foo final {
    // ...
};
```

More interesting that the same syntax is valid for unions:

```
union Foo final {
    // ...
};
```

From the [cpp.reference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final):

> **final can also be used with a union definition, in which case it has
>    no effect (other than on the outcome of std::is_final), since unions
>    cannot be derived from)**

It looks like the usage of *final specifier* with unions is nonsensical. If so, why is it even possible to mark union as final? Just for consistency? Or for some stuff concerning *type_traits*? Did I miss something and are there situations where we need to use *final* with unions?

Comment: If you have a fetish for "no effect". Which is far from "nonsensical".

Comment: @ddriver Sorry, I didn't catch that. What do you mean by "fetish"?

Comment: I mean exactly what it means.

Comment: It's probably because a `union` is considered a class, so the `final` keyword applies to it.

Comment: @AndyG It basically means, that the single reason is a consistence...

Comment: More like poor type hierarchy and/or legacy stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Like you said, `union` can't be derived, so the `final` specifier has absolutely no effect on them. **Other** than the outcome of [`std::is_final`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_final), which behavior can be tested using the code below, where all assertions pass:

```
struct P final { };
union U1 { };
union U2 final { }; // 'union' with 'final' specifier

template <class T>
void test_is_final()
{
    static_assert( std::is_final<T>::value, "");
    static_assert( std::is_final<const T>::value, "");
    static_assert( std::is_final<volatile T>::value, "");
    static_assert( std::is_final<const volatile T>::value, "");
}

template <class T>
void test_is_not_final()
{
    static_assert(!std::is_final<T>::value, "");
    static_assert(!std::is_final<const T>::value, "");
    static_assert(!std::is_final<volatile T>::value, "");
    static_assert(!std::is_final<const volatile T>::value, "");
}

int main()
{
   test_is_final    <P>(); 
   test_is_not_final<P*>();    
   test_is_not_final<U1>();
   test_is_not_final<U1*>();
   test_is_final    <U2>(); // 'std::is_final' on a 'union' with 'final' specifier
   test_is_not_final<U2*>();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be using third-party libraries (even from the same firm, but no write access) that depend on `std::is_final<T>`. A common example is a semi-properly written singleton pattern: you definitely don't want BaseSingleton and DerivedSingleton to be instantiated in parallel. A (notoriously bad) way to prevent this is to `std::enable_if<>` for `std::is_final<T>`. Thus you need to be able to specify it somehow. The question is, why unions are not final automatically.